# Calculate ProgressBar value according to total file size c#

Tags: c#, progress-bar, downloadfileasync

I need to calculate the progress bar value from total size of multiple files using `DownloadFileTaskAsync`. If I use `DownloadProgressChanged`'s `e.ProgressPercentage` it calculates the percentage according to file being downloaded and Progress bar fills and resets as every file downloaded.

I have `totalFileSize` and I'm trying to calculate like this

```
 webClient.DownloadProgressChanged += (sender, e) => 
 {
    currentDownloadedBytes += e.BytesReceived;
    MainWindow.mainWindow.ProgressBar.Value = currentDownloadedBytes / totalFileSize;
 }
```

progress bar value goes until %2200 with the formula I used.

Comment: wouldn't it be currentDownloadedBytes / totalFileSize?
just use ProgressBar.Maximum = totalFileSize
and ProgressBar.Value = currentDownloadedBytes

Comment: yeah you are right, it was a copy-paste issue, i will correct it right away

Comment: you need to seperate `e.BytesReceived` according to which download it's refering to...

Comment: After all those discussions, I got a downvote. Well, thanks.